# Difference between IRQ and FIQ in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, interrupt

What is the difference between IRQ and FIQ as per the Linux API wise? Are they use same api?
Is the difference only inside ARM core or is it do do with the kernel function calls also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they use different APIs.  The best place to look is in `arch/arm/kernel/fiq.c` of the kernel tree.  It looks like there are a few drivers in the tree that use it that may be helpful as examples.

Comment: I checked the code. The handling of IRQ and FIQ happens differently. Is the defining of FIQ & IRQ  to a driver writer is same? For example, If i use "request_irq" api for IRQ then is the same way I am going to defined FIQ with same API or is there different apis?

Comment: Yes and no.  You use `request_irq`, but you also need to call `claim_fiq` as well.  Have a look at this driver: `./drivers/spi/spi_s3c24xx.c`.  It's well-written, and I think it'll be straight-forward to follow the example they've set.